# Should I promote a product while there's a different product with a quite similar name?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, name

I'm going to release a new software tool, currently named "ALM Performance".

I'm now googling, and I see there's a tool named "HP ALM Performance Center" which is highly ranked for "ALM Performance" term. This tool is for different audience, however I'm wondering if it's a good practice to keep the planned "ALM Performance" name or should I find another name?
Thank you!

P.S. This question is about SEO of course... not about legal... "ALM" and "Performance" are generic words and do not belong to any company.

P.S 2: Both tools are for audience in software industry. My tool is for administrators and developers, while the other tool is for software testers and quality assurance.

Answer (score 5):

Using ALM Performance as your keyword will mean you always struggle to compete with HP for that search term and anyone searching for your tool will find the HP tool instead, I would suggest choosing an alternate name.

Comment: I'd be hard to compete with the weight of a player as HP. Make up an inedit fantasy name and go with that.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you can promote the same, If you can't compete HP you will definitely get rank next to HP and if you have effective marketing strategy than you can even get higher rank to HP, but note that it can take long time to get rank ahead HP as they have huge traffic on their website.

I think you might face Copyright Issue for name, if they had registered the same name.

Comment: Thanks. I checked with trademark search engines. So far I found no relevant trademarks.